# AlarmManager use setExactAndAllowWhileIdle so it repeats

Tags: android, alarm

I have an app that uses an AlarmManager to schedule a service to repeat at a set frequency, say every hour.

From Android 6, devices will drop into Doze mode, this mode ignores wakelock and Alarms, potentially running them in the maintenance window. I would prefer that the Alarm executes when it is scheduled even if the device is in low-power idle modes.

I understand i can use setExactAndAllowWhileIdle to execute the alarm in Doze but this will excute only once. I cannot see any method that has this functionality but will repeat at a set frequency.

for example i use the code below to fire an alarm every hour. Is there a way to use setExactAndAllowWhileIdle so it repeats?

```
                             // get a Calendar object with current time
                             Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
                             // add 5 minutes to the calendar object
                             cal2.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 1);
                             Intent intentTracking = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TrackingAlarmReceiver.class);

                             // In reality, you would want to have a static variable for the request code instead of 192837
                             PendingIntent sender3 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 192839, intentTracking, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                             // Get the AlarmManager service
                             AlarmManager am3 = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                             //am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), sender);


                             am3.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal2.getTimeInMillis(), ((Integer.parseInt(carerTrackingInteval)) * 60000 ), sender3);
```

Comment: I think you need to reshedule it on each trigger while working with DOZE and `setExactAndAllowWhileIdle`. This is just an assumption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ADM [is spot-on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48339484/alarmmanager-use-setexactandallowwhileidle-so-it-repeats#comment83664346_48339484).

As part of the work in `TrackingAlarmReceiver`, you call `setExactAndAllowWhileIdle()` to schedule the next bit of work.

Bear in mind that the minimum granularity of such events is ~10 minutes IIRC, and that you may not have network access even though you get control.

Comment: Thinking about it Mark, My MDM/EMM system has about 8 services that are scheduled at different time around 10 mins apart. The customers will chose how often they want these service to sync their device with the MDM. I honestly think that there could be situations where one alarm has executed and then 6 mins later another is due to. Like the docs say, 9 mins must elapse before another Alarm can be executed.  I think maybe a better way would be to have the MDM send a push to the device on a timer. This would ping the device asking to sync. what do you think?

Comment: Another way would be to just leave the code as-is(using setRepeating) and just let Android defer the functionality to maintenance windows?

Comment: @turtleboy: "I think maybe a better way would be to have the MDM send a push to the device on a timer. This would ping the device asking to sync. what do you think?" -- technically, that's a possibility. It has a bunch of requirements (Internet access, a server team willing to set this up, etc.), so I do not know whether it is practical for your situation. "Another way would be to just leave the code as-is(using setRepeating) and just let Android defer the functionality to maintenance windows?" - sure, or use `JobScheduler`, but timing can get very sporadic.

Comment: Ok thanks, I already have the MDM finished, it has taken 2.5 years. It uses the Knox apis that you recommended to me years ago. 2500 api calls implemented and 500 push notifications later, it is going to test with a company next week :) Another push notification won't harm to sync. Thanks again